# Suma de subarreglos

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo sumar, o bueno, cuál sería la lógica para sumar el contenido de un arreglo? Por ejemplo:

Entrada:
Tamaño: 5
Números a sumar: 3
Array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Salida:
6 9 12

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        num = arr [i] + arr [m-1+i];
        cout << "" << num << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: qué haz intentado?...

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Si sabes sumar los elementos de un arreglo deberías ser capaz de hacer esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas dos bucles anidados. El primer bucle recorre el array y el segundo se encarga de ir haciendo las sumas

```
for(int i=0; i<n-m; i++)
{
    int suma = 0;

    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        suma += arr[i + j];
    }

    std::cout << suma << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// funcion que suma los elementos del subarray y retorna la suma
int sumar(int arr[], int posicionInicial, int tam){
    int suma = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        suma += arr[posicionInicial++];
    }

    return suma;
}

int main(){
    int tam, sumandos, numCiclos, resultado;

    cin>>tam>>sumandos;

    int arr[tam];

    // llenar array
    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // calcular iteraciones
    numCiclos = tam - sumandos + 1;

    // recorrer array no elemento por elemento
    // sino por la cantidad de veces que resulta de los numeros a sumar
    for(int i = 0; i < numCiclos; i++){
        resultado = sumar(arr,i,sumandos);
        cout<<resultado<<" ";
    }

    cout<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo termine ese mismo dia, aqui el codigo:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main (){
     int n, m;
     cin >> n >> m;
     int arr[n], num = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          cin >> arr[i];

     for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
          num += arr[i];

     cout << num;

     for (int i = m; i < n; i++){
         num -= arr[i - m];
         num += arr[i];
         cout << " " << num;
   }
  }
```

Comment: No olvides explicar cómo funciona tu código. Lee [answer].